# Impala - Convert MON-YY to YYYYMM

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I have one column Month_year in staging table having below data. Please suggest query to get the desired output.

Input:

```
+----------+
month_year
+----------+
Jan-19
Dec-18
+----------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+----------+
month_year
+----------+
201901
201812
+----------+
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If column's month_year date format is MMM-yy then contact 01 as default date for avoid to null result, however it will not effect expected out because you are going to get output in format yyyyMM.  
Try this:  
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('01-',month_year),'dd-MMM-yy'),'yyyyMM')
```

Comment: Month_year column is string type. please suggest solution to convert String to yyyyMM (String type)

Comment: try the query, since from_unixtime functions will return string hence need not required to convert to String.